# Component Elements Re render & duplicate, but fix on refresh

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, react-redux

I am creating an app which can display projects, this project has a few child components and server-side functions running when a user creates a new project. This results in the props changing which causes the ProjectList to refresh which is fine but it then also produces two of the submitted project when in the database it shows one and when you refresh it displays one.

[Screenshot of duplicated project entry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhfJI.png)

[After page refresh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5Tin.png)

As it works after refresh it makes me think its something to do with the state?

So I have a Dashboard component - > ProjectList -> ProjectListDetails

Dashboard code

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { firestoreConnect } from "react-redux-firebase";
import ProjectList from "../Projects/ProjectList";
import { compose } from "redux";
import CreateProject from "../Projects/CreateProject";
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

class Dashboard extends Component {
  render() {
    const { projects, auth, profile, organisations } = this.props;
    if (!auth.uid) return <Redirect to="/signin" />;
    //is the logged in user an Organisation or Single account?
    const isOrg =
      profile.isOrg === true ? (
        <p>Organisation Account</p>
      ) : (
        <p>Single Account</p>
      );

    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row home-header-row">
          <div className="col-md-12 section text-center">
            {isOrg}
            <br></br>

            <CreateProject organisations={organisations} />
            <ProjectList
              projects={projects}
              authID={auth.uid}
              profile={profile}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    projects: state.firestore.ordered.projects,
    auth: state.firebase.auth,
    profile: state.firebase.profile,
    notifications: state.firestore.ordered.notifications,
    organisations: state.firestore.ordered.organisations
  };
};

export default compose(
  connect(mapStateToProps),
  firestoreConnect([
    { collection: "projects", orderBy: ["totalEntries", "desc"] },
    { collection: "organisations", orderBy: ["time", "desc"] },
    { collection: "notifications", limit: 5, orderBy: ["time", "desc"] }
  ])
)(Dashboard);
```

Project List Component :

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ProjectListDetails from "./ProjectListDetails";

import "firebase/firestore";

class ProjectList extends Component {
  // shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
  //     return this.props.projects !== nextProps.projects;
  //   }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="project-list section">
        {this.props.projects &&
          this.props.projects.map(project => {
            const projectId =
              project.authorID +
              project.createdAt.toDate().toLocaleTimeString("it-it") +
              project.title;

            return (
              <>
                {project.canView.includes(this.props.profile.email) ||
                project.authorEmail.includes(this.props.profile.email) ? (
                  <ProjectListDetails
                    project={project}
                    profile={this.props.profile}
                    projectId={projectId}
                  ></ProjectListDetails>
                ) : null}
              </>
            );
          })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ProjectList;
```

ProjectListDetails Component

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

import EditProject from "./EditProjects";
import DeleteProject from "./DeleteProject";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import ProjectSummary from "./ProjectSummary";

class ProjectListDetails extends Component {
  render() {
    console.log("printing project : " + this.props.project.title);

    return (
      <div className="row" key={this.props.project.id}>
        <div className="col-md-12" key={this.props.project.projectID}>
          <button
            className="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle project-options"
            type="button"
            id="dropdownMenuButton"
            data-toggle="dropdown"
            aria-haspopup="true"
            aria-expanded="false"
          >
            Options
          </button>
          <div
            className="dropdown-menu"
            aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton"
            id={this.props.project.projectID}
          >
            <EditProject />
            <DeleteProject />
          </div>

          <Link
            to={"/project/" + this.props.project.id}
            key={this.props.project.id}
            profile={this.props.profile}
            projectId={this.props.projectId}
          >
            <ProjectSummary
              projectId={this.props.projectId}
              project={this.props.project}
              key={this.props.project.id}
              authID={this.props.authID}
            />
          </Link>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ProjectListDetails;
```

CreateProject Component

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { createProject } from "../../Store/Actions/projectActions";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";
import Modal from "react-bootstrap/Modal";

// import ReactQuill from 'react-quill'
// import 'react-quill/dist/quill.snow.css'
// import renderHTML from 'react-render-html';

class CreateProject extends Component {
  state = {
    title: "",
    content: "",
    projectAmount: 0,
    commentAmount: 0,
    hideModal: false,
    showModal: "",
    show: false,
    setShow: false,
    canView: [],
    organisation: ""
  };

  handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.id]: e.target.value
    });
  };

  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    this.setState({ canView: [] });

    this.props.organisations &&
      this.props.organisations.map(organisation => {
        if (organisation.canView.includes(this.props.profile.email)) {
          const orgUser = organisation.canView.map((item, key) =>
            this.state.canView.push(item)
          );
          return orgUser;
        }
        return null;
      });
    this.props.createProject(this.state);

    document.getElementById("title").value = "";
    document.getElementById("content").value = "";
  };

  handleClose = () => {
    this.setState({
      show: false
    });
  };
  handleShow = () => {
    this.setState({
      show: true
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <Button
          className="btn btn-primary"
          variant="primary"
          onClick={this.handleShow}
        >
          New Project
        </Button>

        <Modal show={this.state.show} onHide={this.handleClose}>
          <Modal.Header closeButton>
            <Modal.Title>New Project</Modal.Title>
          </Modal.Header>
          <Modal.Body>
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
              <div className="form-group">
                <input
                  onChange={this.handleChange}
                  className="form-control"
                  type="text"
                  id="title"
                  placeholder="Project Title"
                />
              </div>
              <div className="form-group">
                <textarea
                  onChange={this.handleChange}
                  className="form-control"
                  id="content"
                  rows="3"
                  placeholder="Project Content (can add some more options here later)"
                ></textarea>
              </div>
              <Modal.Footer>
                <Button variant="secondary" onClick={this.handleClose}>
                  Close
                </Button>
                <Button
                  type="submit"
                  variant="primary"
                  onClick={this.handleClose}
                >
                  Save Changes
                </Button>
              </Modal.Footer>
            </form>
          </Modal.Body>
        </Modal>
      </>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    projects: state.firestore.ordered.projects,
    auth: state.firebase.auth,
    profile: state.firebase.profile,
    organisations: state.firestore.ordered.organisations
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    createProject: project => dispatch(createProject(project))
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(CreateProject);
```

Project Action

```
export const createProject = project => {
  return (dispatch, getState, { getFirebase, getFirestore }) => {
    // make async call to database
    const firestore = getFirestore();
    const profile = getState().firebase.profile;
    const authorId = getState().firebase.auth.uid;
    const createdAt = new Date();
    const convertedDate = createdAt.toLocaleTimeString("it-it");
    const printFirstName =
      profile.isOrg === true ? profile.orgFirstName : profile.firstName;
    const printLastName =
      profile.isOrg === true ? profile.orgLastName : profile.lastName;
    const projectId = authorId + convertedDate + project.title;
    const orgName = profile.organisation ? profile.organisation : "";

    //this.state.project.createdAt.toDate().toLocaleTimeString('it-it') + this.state.project.title

    firestore
      .collection("projects")
      .doc(projectId)
      .set({
        ...project,
        authorFirstName: printFirstName,
        authorLastname: printLastName,
        authorID: authorId,
        authorEmail: profile.email,
        canView: project.canView,
        canEdit: [profile.email],
        createdAt: createdAt,
        projectID: projectId,
        organisation: orgName,
        permalink: "/project/" + projectId
      })
      .then(() => {
        dispatch({ type: "CREATE_PROJECT", project });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        dispatch({ type: "CREATE_PROJECT_ERROR", err });
      });
    //
  };
};
```

ProjectReducer

```
const initState = {};

const projectReducer = (state = initState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "CREATE_PROJECT":
      return state;
    case "DELETE_PROJECT":
      console.log("Project Deleted", action.project);
      return state;
    case "CREATE_PROJECT_ERROR":
      console.log("Create project error", action.err);
      return state;
    case "DELETE_PROJECT_ERROR":
      console.log("Delete project error", action.err);
      return state;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default projectReducer;
```

Firebase Function

```
exports.projectInnerEntries = functions.firestore
  .document("projects/{projectId}")
  .onWrite((change, context) => {
    const newValue = change.after.data();
    var projectAmount = newValue.projectAmount;
    var commentAmount = newValue.commentAmount;
    // var totalEntries = projectAmount + commentAmount;
    const notification = {
      projects: projectAmount,
      comments: commentAmount,
      total: projectAmount + commentAmount
    };

    return admin
      .firestore()
      .collection("projects")
      .doc(newValue.projectID)
      .update({
        totalEntries: notification.total
      });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your ProjectList component is holding the previous state inside it,When you are adding new Project,the firestore is giving you the projects list ,but i think you are displaying the projects using array.push method in ProjectList component.Can you share ProjectList Component?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, ive now added the other components.

Comment: How many arrays are you getting inside the render method of ProjectListDetails component when you are adding a new project??

Comment: It maps out all of the projects from my firebase database and then filters them if they are in an organisation. Those then get put into the ProjectListDetails Component. It looks like it re-renders multiple times, would this cause it to accidentally show multiple elements of one component?

Comment: I also have a firebase server side function which adds together total projects + comments so I can show the projects with higher amount of project+comments at the top.

Comment: can you add the CreateProject Component to the post ?so that i can understand more why its happening?

Comment: I appreciate you looking at this, I've now added it. Thank you

Comment: no issues,can you also add the create project action and reducer?

Comment: you can sign up and make a project if you want to see it live here: https://boomapp-8d7cc.firebaseapp.com/

Comment: I've added my firebase function as well for you to look at

Comment: i see there is no problem with the firestore ,as it is storing only one!,and  when you are creating a new project ,you are fetching directly from the firestore,try deleting this dispatch({ type: "CREATE_PROJECT", project }); line and let me know

Comment: i've deleted that line from projectActions and it is still doing it

Comment: When i remove my Firebase server side function it fixes the problem but I don't know how to fix it.. When the firebase function runs it changes the props so thats why it refreshes the component again, but why does it show multiple of new entries?...and then clears on refresh

Comment: yeah i've already done that, the bug is showing on the live site

Comment: Hi alex ,now i can not even see the projects i added after adding comments to one project ,in console i can see the list of projects ,but in dashboard i am getting empty

Comment: Sorry I was testing some bits, its back up now

Comment: Hey man did you solve it,I couldn't find any answers,if you did find a solution let me know.

Comment: Hey warmachine, yes I did fix it in the end. It was because I had multiple components with mapStateToProps, i reduced this down to just the parent having this and then passing the values in props and it worked fine. Now im having an issue where the props are not loading when logged in though, need to refresh for these props to show